A property of matrices formed by pairing of roots and coroots
Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ integral matrix, define its level $l(A)$ as
$$l(A) := \begin{cases}0 &\det A = 0 \\ \text{smallest integer } N \text{ such that } NA^{-1} \text{ is integral} &\det A \neq 0\end{cases}$$
For a simple crystallographic root system $\Phi$, $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_r$ be its positive roots, $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n$ be associated fundamental weights. Consider the $n\times r$ integral matrix $M_\Phi := (\lambda_i,\alpha_j^\vee)$. Define $$l(\Phi) := \{ l(A) | A \text{ being } n\times n \text{ submatrix of } M_\Phi \}$$
As an example, for $\Phi = B_3$, $$M_\Phi = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right)
$$
By computing $l(\bullet)$ of all its $3\times 3$ submatrices, (there are $\binom{9}{3} = 84$ many), one obtains $l(B_3) = \{0,1,2\}$.

Some experimentation suggests following is true:

Is $l(\Phi) = \{0,1,2\}$ for $\Phi = B_n, C_n, D_n$?

Moreover, is there is a conceptual interpretation of $l(\Phi)$? Thank you very much.

I got $l(E_6) = {0, 1, 2, 3}$. For the next rank I would have to let it run over night so please feel free to use my code: https://pastebin.com/U2ny4Pad
Disclaimer: I don't know what denominator of a matrix means in Sagemath context, but I guess it is the LCM of the denominators of the matrix entries. I tested this on SageMath 10.4.

I forgot to add that you get the resulting level like this set(calculate_levels("E6").values())
